# How do I Preload relational data in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am building an iOS app in Xcode 9 using CoreData. I need to be able to provide a default set of data that can pre-populate the app and also be used for a default in case or resetting the app.

I have the following code for importing a single array of data using a plist:

```
private func preloadData() {

    let preloadDataKey = "didPreloadData"

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: preloadDataKey) == false {

    guard let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PreloadData", withExtension: "plist") else { return }


    let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true

    backgroundContext.perform {

        if let arrayContents = NSArray(contentsOf: urlPath) as? [String] {

            do {

            for companyName in arrayContents {
                let companyObject = Company(context: backgroundContext)
                companyObject.name = companyName
            }

            try backgroundContext.save()
                userDefaults.set(true, forKey: preloadDataKey)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

However, the data I need to import is relational with two entities and multiple attributes for each. How would I do that?

Comment: You say that the data is relational with two entities but you haven't explained why this is a problem? Is your Core Data design very different or is it an issue with maintaining the relationships or...?

Comment: From the example I am working with there is no relationship, it is a single array. However, in my own app the there are two entities with attributes and relationship between them. I am not familiar with how such information is displayed in a Plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with two entities, `CarMaker` and `CarModel`. I have used an array of dictionaries in my plist and each dictionary is a `CarModel` instance and the relationship is de-normalized in such a way that all attributes for `CarMaker` is repeated for each `CarModel`, in my example it is only the attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Cars</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>engine</key>
            <string>Diesel</string>
            <key>maker</key>
            <string>Volvo</string>
            <key>model</key>
            <string>V70</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>engine</key>
            <string>Petrol</string>
            <key>maker</key>
            <string>Volvo</string>
            <key>model</key>
            <string>XC90</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When reading this I would use a cache (dictionary) in my swift code that holds the already created CarMaker instances to avoid duplicates in Core Data

Comment: I think we are getting closer with this. My data structure would be something like this:
   Season
      Task
         Title
        Detail

There is a one to many relationship between the season and the tasks. Would that be done in a similar structure to what you have above?

Comment: Yes it is since I have a one-to-many relationship between CarMaker and CarModel in my example. So create a structure like above with a dictionary for each Task where each Task also contains a complete Season object.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this.